# AttributeError: 'OneVsRestClassifier' object has no attribute 'coef_'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Please this is an emergency. When I looked at the solved examples, there were solutions on linear regression, I don't know what to fix in my own code. I would be glad if you help.I think I need to solve it with fit() function. But I couldn't figure out where to do the fix. You can find all the codes on this site. I'm leaving the link in case there's more for you to look at: https://www.kaggle.com/code/miljan/predicting-tags-for-stackoverflow/notebook
This is my code block where i get error:

```
 def print_top10(feature_names, clf, class_labels):
    Prints features with the highest coefficient values, per class
    for i, class_label in enumerate(class_labels):
        top10 = np.argsort(clf.coef_[i])[-10:]
        print("--------------------------------------------")
        print("%s: %s" % (class_label,
              " ".join(feature_names[j] for j in top10)))
        print("--------------------------------------------")
    feature_names = vectorizer_X1.get_feature_names_out() + vectorizer_X2.get_feature_names_out()
    print_top10(feature_names, best_model, multilabel_binarizer.classes_)
```

Comment: Hello. Please give the full stracktrace.